# Bizarre behavior of GMSCameraPosition-GMSMapView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash, ios10, gmsmapview

Hy,
This is the very bizarre behavior of `GMSCameraPosition`. The code crashes some time that is written in `viewDidLoad`, saying `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000008`. I am using google maps. Here is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = TRUE;
GMSCameraPosition *camera =
[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[AppConfig sharedInstance].theLocation.latitude
                            longitude:[AppConfig sharedInstance].theLocation.longitude
                                 zoom:14];

homeMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera]; // Code crashes here
homeMapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
homeMapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
homeMapView.settings.zoomGestures = YES;
homeMapView.delegate = self;
self.view = homeMapView;
}
```

How to sort it, if anyone faced this kind of behaviour. Here is crashlytics stack, please help:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18a7fa804 object_isClass + 24
1  Foundation                     0x18c7d49b8 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 328
2  HooSafe                        0x100465f94 -[GMSMapView internalSetCamera:] + 4299415444
3  HooSafe                        0x100462608 -[GMSMapView setCamera:] + 4299400712
4  HooSafe                        0x100460f8c -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:forPlaces:] + 4299394956
5  HooSafe                        0x10045ff84 -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:] + 4299390852
6  HooSafe                        0x10045fdc8 +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:] + 4299390408
7  HooSafe                        0x10011dc14 -[DemoViewController viewDidLoad] (DemoViewController.m:107)
8  UIKit                          0x191c7a924 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1056
9  UIKit                          0x191d342bc -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
10 UIKit                          0x191d34194 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
11 UIKit                          0x191d334dc -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 140
12 UIKit                          0x191d32f28 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 856
13 UIKit                          0x191d32adc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
14 UIKit                          0x191d32a40 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
15 UIKit                          0x191c77a80 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1196
16 QuartzCore                     0x18f1259d8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
17 QuartzCore                     0x18f11a4cc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
18 QuartzCore                     0x18f11a38c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
19 QuartzCore                     0x18f0973e0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
20 QuartzCore                     0x18f0bea68 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
21 QuartzCore                     0x18f0bf488 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18bd720c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18bd6fcf0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18bd70180 __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18bc9e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
26 GraphicsServices               0x18d752198 GSEventRunModal + 180
27 UIKit                          0x191ce57fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
28 UIKit                          0x191ce0534 UIApplicationMain + 208
29 HooSafe                        0x1000b12d0 main (main.m:16)
30 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ac815b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: did you ever manage to find a solution/he cause for this?